# PHP click ling and open new PHP page according to ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html

Question is:

I have a PHP webpage with list of data taken from database.

```
---------------------------------------
----- ID117 ----- aaa ------ bbb ------
----- ID118 ----- aaa ------ bbb ------
----- ID119 ----- aaa ------ bbb ------
----- ID120 ----- aaa ------ bbb ------
----- ID121 ----- aaa ------ bbb ------
---------------------------------------
```

All what i need is: by clicking  ID120 for example, it will open separate webpage with information from another database WHERE ID = ID120.

EG:

Click **ID120:**

Another page opened with this info:

ID120

City = UK,

Phone number = 1234234124

and so on....

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

include 'connect/con.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM newsvid");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>vidTitle</th>
<th>imgCover</th>
<th>vidSD</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vidTitle'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['imgCover'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vidSD'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have another database called **videoInformation**  so I need, by clicking ID  open another webpage  with information from another database where ID = which one was clicked.

Basically I'm not sure where to start. (

Comment: We answer questions related to source code problems and programming. Which exact problem with your code do you face? In other words: Please show your source and what you have tried so far. What is working - what is not...

Comment: Updated, have a look

Comment: Thanks. Now we have something we can work with.

Comment: create a link on each row with the id in a get parameter. then use a prepared statement to retrieve the info for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have just the output of the database:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
```

Let's change that to include a link:

```
echo '<td><a href="videoinfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['vidTitle'] . '</a></td>';
```

We added the `<a>` (anchor) tag for a html link. The href attribute points to videoinfo.php. 
This file will be used for your videoInformation querying. 
We are passing the $row['id'] via a GET request to the videoinfo.php by simply appending to the href URL.

---

Then create a file `videoinfo.php`:

```
<?php

// here we get the incomming video id (videoinfo.php?id=123)
$video_id = $_GET['id'];

// build a database query to select the videoInformation
// here we use WHERE to select the video_id we want
$query = 'SELECT * FROM videoInformationTable WHERE video_id = ' . $video_id;

// lets connect and do the query
include 'connect/con.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

--

Important Note:
When working with a database you should read about "SQL injection" and "escaping".
You are working with mysqli, so please read about a function called [real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
The manual also includes an example on how to apply the escaping correctly.

Also: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: want to sanitise that before his database gets destroyed. oh and the link aint right

Comment: You should link to some helpful topics on SQL Injection. If he takes your code and uses it as is (lots of people do) he'll get annihilated...

Comment: He is a beginner - he wants to get started. But you both learned about SQL injection before build a anchor tag, right.. come on.. Also: this question is not about, how can i secure my video database which has 1 mio hits...

Comment: Basically for now I try to understand basic idea, after i will improve the code and will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '<td><a href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></td>';
```

on details.php, check the id `$_GET['id']` and use that in the query for the details

Comment: and on details.php page how do display info where ID = clicked one?

SELECT * FROM videoInformation WHERE id = id? ... sorry confused a bit, but you mostly solved my problem.